# How to change the size of the textbox, make it long in asp.net core defalut template

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am trying to make a form in which the required input is lager. And that default `<input ="text">` size is not enough. I tried `size=""` and also `width=""` but it is not giving any change. I am using asp.net core default website templates. Is there any size limit? If there is, how can I change it? Please help me to change the size of the textbox.

Comment: please enter code....

Comment: it is hard to tell you without seeing the code what u wrote to assign value to textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" style="min-width:100%"/>
```

I added `style ="min-width:100%"` as shown above and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `col-md-x` bootstrap class on the div that wraps your textbox like this-

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the value of rows and cols you can change the size of text area

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

This textarea has 10 visible rows.

You can change that by changing the value of the "rows" attribute.